# Swift, how to declare methods requiring instance members while following MVC

Tags: ios, swift, oop, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use the MVC in an app loading a url into a webView. I'm struggling with how to/whether to define the back, forward, reload, etc... functions in the model or the viewController. I'm pretty sure they belong in the model, but then how do I call them in the IBAction for the corresponding button?

In trying to call the class function in the IBAction, first I have to create an instance of WebViewLoadRequest in each IBAction which seems extraneous. I can't (and probably shouldn't) create a global instance of WebViewLoadRequest because self isn't available in the property initializer to reference the UIWebView Outlet

```
 class WebViewLoadRequest {
  var outlet: UIWebView
  var url : String
  private var address: URL

  init(outlet: UIWebView, url: String) {
    self.outlet = outlet
    self.url = url
    self.address = URL(string: url)!
  }

  func load() {
    self.outlet.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:address))
  }

  func back() {
    if outlet.canGoBack {
      outlet.goBack()
    }
  }

  func forward() {
    if outlet.canGoForward {
      outlet.goForward()
    }
  }

  func refresh() {
    outlet.reload()
  }

}
```

To simplify:

How can I write the following function in the model layer and implement it in the ViewController?

```
//outlet refers to a UIWebView
func back() {
    if outlet.canGoBack {
      outlet.goBack()
    }
  }
```

Or should this strictly be a function of the view controller? I realize essentially just the view is being changed, but there's a lot going on behind the scenes in the goBack operation that I'm not sure belongs in the ViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two things here IMO, there is object oriented programming which you described in your question. There is also another concept which is commonly used and also very common in Swift, this concept is MVC. Model, **View**, Controller. This is basically a seperation of powers. In practice this comes down to:

**Model** - custom class with all the logic, in your case the WebViewLoadRequest

**View** - defined in a 'storyboard'

**Controller** - Will be a subclass of UIViewController, this subclass also has a reference to your model, all the IBActions and IBOutlets to connect to and update your UI.

You can learn more about MVC here:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach

Also I would **strongly** recommend watching the C193p course from Standford by Paul Hegarty, this teaches you all there is to know. For example the 4th week is about MVC
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-10-apps-with-swift/id1198467120

EDIT:
Basically your construction is a construction of delegation. The normal way to solve this issue is by creating a delegate property on your model-class, the delegate implements a certain protocol with for example a 'canIGoBack'-function. The model can request extra data from the delegate by calling that delegate function. Apple has something about delegation in their swift manual (check the 'Delegation' part:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

I believe Paul Hegarty also discussed it.

However, in this case it is also fine to do the canGoBack in the viewcontroller and conditionally call your model. MVC is only a guideline, there are many reasons to sometimes do logic in a viewcontroller, the biggest reason is probably if it makes shit easier. Implementing delegation only for a canGoBack is most of the times just silly.

Comment: I'm learning about MVC and trying to implement it here by defining the class in the model layer and implementing what I need from it in the ViewController. MVC and OOP aren't exclusive. From what I understand, either OOP or POP is required in order to implement MVC. Thanks much for the links, Paul Hegarty is great. That said, can I just not implement methods from a class outside of the ViewController in Storyboard elements?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean, if you have a viewcontroller with a reference to the class, you can define an IBAction in your viewcontroller and in the action call a method from your models class. You can only connect storyboard elements to a corresponding class, so elements in a viewcontroller can be connected to the class of the viewcontroller (probably subclass of UIViewController). You cannot connect UI elements to a random other class which you use as model somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, if I had multiple webViews in multiple ViewControllers, then I'd probably want to create a delegate property on the class in the model to avoid repeating code, but for 1 or 2 views, you're probably right that breaking MVC is preferred